# JQuery: this returns [object Window]

Tags: jquery, html, object, this

So I'm working on a search bar, similar to the interface on http://www.justdelete.me .

I have put tags on each item, so I can search for related terms, and still get the same result. So I basically have a list within each list item. Here's the HTML so you know what I mean:

```
    <ul class="list">
        <li>
            <h2 class='Item-list'>
                Car
            </h2>
            <ul class="tags" id='car'>
                <li class="tag">vehicle</li> 
                <li class="tag">autombile</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2 class='Item-list'>
                House
            </h2>
            <ul class="tags" id='house'>
                <li class="tag">house</li>
                <li class="tag">domicile</li>
                <li class="tag">residence</li>
                <li class="tag">house</li>
                <li class="tag">home</li>
            </ul>       
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2 class='Item-list'>
                Bag
            </h2>
            <ul class="tags" id='bag'>
                <li class="tag">bag</li>
                <li class="tag">bag</li>
                <li class="tag">rucksack</li>
                <li class="tag">suitcase</li>
            </ul>   
        </li>
```

And my jquery to hide and show the items is as follows:

```
    //hide and show items
    $(".tags:contains('" + searchquery + "')").parentsUntil(this, 'li').removeClass('no-display');
    $(".tags:not(:contains('" + searchquery + "'))").parentsUntil(this, 'li').addClass('no-display');
```

So until now no problem.

The problem arises when I try to change the h2 containing the item title to whatever i type in the search box.

So say i type in 'V'. I would like my car h2, to change to Vehicle, as it is one of the tags of car.

I tried to use the following code:

```
    "use strict";
    $(".tag:contains('" + searchquery + "')").parentsUntil(this, 'li').children().first().replaceWith('<h2 class="Item-list">'+this+' </h2>');
```

But instead of changing to Vehicle, it changes to the text:  [object Window]

Thank you very much in advance!

EDIT: Here's the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/6f8F8/2/

Comment: can you edit [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6f8F8/1/) to recreate your problem

Comment: <h2 class="Item-list">'+this+' </h2>   or <h2 class="Item-list">'+ searchquery +' </h2> ??

Comment: <h2 class="Item-list">'+`this`+' </h2> 
It should be `$(this).text()` or `$(this).html()`

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle with enough code context to let us undersatnd your issue and what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

`this` refer to the current object, you need to get the `text` or `html` inside your element instead, so try to use **[text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)**:

```
$(".tag:contains('" + searchquery + "')").parentsUntil(this, 'li').children().first().replaceWith('<h2 class="Item-list">'+ $(this).text() +' </h2>');
```

or **[html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)**:

```
$(".tag:contains('" + searchquery + "')").parentsUntil(this, 'li').children().first().replaceWith('<h2 class="Item-list">'+ $(this).html() +' </h2>');
```

Comment: Neither of these worked. When I used .text() the h2 went blank, and when I used .html() , the h2 didn't change. Thank you anyways